# How to connect to HBase table using spark without scanning entire table and get specific known row keys data

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I am having a massive number of row keys,  need to get data of those row keys without scanning entire table or loading entire table into spark as table is very big

Comment: Any hbase client will read columns, never scan an entire table unless you tell it to select every column

Comment: can you provide connector script?

Comment: Below answer already does

Answer (score 1):

There are many HBase-Spark libraries, but many of them are old and they are not mantained. So I prefer old reliable methods.

Try the following.

I have `'word_counts'` HBase table, with `'counts'` column family.
In my case there is `'counts:count'` column which is `Long`.

I will use `newAPIHadoopRDD` method and HBase access by `hbase-mapreduce` library

Let's start (I am using Apache Spark 3.1.3, but it should work for any Spark version)

```
spark-shell --master yarn --packages org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:2.2.7,org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:2.2.7,org.apache.hbase:hbase-mapreduce:2.2.7
```

My code is as follows:

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.PrefixFilter
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan


// This function converts a Scan object to a string representation 
// that can be passed to HBase as a configuration value
def convertScanToString(scan: Scan) = {
  val proto = ProtobufUtil.toScan(scan)
  Base64.encodeBase64String(proto.toByteArray)
}

// Create a new Scan object and set a PrefixFilter 
// to only return rows with keys that start with "s"
val scan = new Scan()
val filter = new PrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes("s"))
scan.setFilter(filter)

// Create a new HBase configuration and set the input table, 
// zookeeper quorum, and scan
val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "word_counts")
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "zookeeper-host")
conf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN, convertScanToString(scan))

// Create an RDD using the HBase configuration and the TableInputFormat
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result])

// Convert the RDD to a DataFrame and set the column names
val df = rdd.map(x => {
  val rowKey = Bytes.toString(x._2.getRow)
  val columnValue = Option(x._2.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("counts"), 
       Bytes.toBytes("count"))).map(value => 
       Bytes.toLong(value).toString).getOrElse("")
  (rowKey, columnValue)
}).toDF("row_key", "column_value")
```

If you are interested only with particular key you can use the following

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{Get, Result}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{HBaseConfiguration, TableName}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val hbaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
hbaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "zookeeper-host")
val tableName = TableName.valueOf("word_counts")
val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(hbaseConf)
val table = connection.getTable(tableName)

val get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("s"))
val result: Result = table.get(get)

val value = Bytes.toString(result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("counts"), Bytes.toBytes("count")))

println(s"Value for key 's' is: $value")

table.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: will this scan load or scan entire table and than do get operation?

Comment: this is working with prefix can we have any function to get exact rowkey data?

Comment: We create a new Scan object and set a PrefixFilter to GET only (and return) these rows (columns) that keys start with "s"

You can use this code and parameterize it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use [gimel](https://gimel.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library, according to md file filter are pushed down to Hbase.

```
What is gimel?

    Gimel is a Big Data Abstraction framework built on Apache Spark & other open source connectors in the industry.
    Gimel provides unified Data API to read & write data to various stores.
    Alongside, a unified SQL access pattern for all stores alike.
    The APIs are available in both scala & python (pyspark).
```

[HBase md file](https://github.com/paypal/gimel/blob/master/docs/gimel-connectors/hbase.md#push-down-filters)

In this md file you will find some examples, maybe they are similar to you use case

```
    gsql("set gimel.hbase.columns.mapping=personal:name,personal:age")
val df = gsql("select * from udc.Hbase.ClusterName.default.test_emp where rowkey='1-MAC'")
df.show

df.explain
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Filter isnotnull(rowkey#181)
+- *(1) Scan HBaseRelation(Map(catalog -> {"table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"test_emp", "tableCoder":"PrimitiveType"},
"rowkey":"rowkey",
"columns":{
"rowkey":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"rowkey", "type":"string", "length":"50"},
"name":{"cf":"personal", "col":"name", "type":"string"},
"age":{"cf":"personal", "col":"age", "type":"string"}
}
}
    ),None) [rowkey#181,name#182,age#183] PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(rowkey), *EqualTo(rowkey,1-MAC)], ReadSchema: struct<rowkey:string,name:string,age:string>
```